# ReusingLithium Polymer battery from an Old Tablet

Tags: batteries, charger, lipo, reuse

One of the projects that I am currently working on requires a backup battery source. I have 2 tablets with me that's that's dead (cracked screen) and the Asus one had a 4270mAh battery. I was trying to figure a way to use it but couldn't find any info. I've attached pictures of the IC. It says 8006 2:39... Does anyone know which IC is this or how I can build a charger for the battery and reuse it for my projects ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the protection switch.  A common way to implement that is with two MOSFETS in anti-series.  Probably something like this:

[image: Anti-series MOSFETS]

This is because a single MOSFET can only stop current in one direction because of the body-diode.  There should be another IC on the board that controls those two MOSFETS.

Comment: I can see another IC on the PCB(5 pin), but it doesn't have any numbering on top of it. I guess they removed it. Any idea how I can build a charger for this battery and how it can be used to power a circuit ? I can see that there are 2 Red Wires, 2 Black Wires, a white one and a yellow one.